# String encoding - German umlaut

Tags: c#, localization, string-length

Using C#, Framework 4.0, I'm facing a tricky problem with the german language.

Considering this `snippet` :

```
string l_stest = "ZÄHLWERKE";
Console.WriteLine(l_stest.Length); // 9
Console.WriteLine(toto.LengthInTextElements); // 9
Console.ReadLine();
```

The result will be `9`;

Now, selecting the text withing `Notepad++`, it will give me a length of `10`.

I'm guessing the `encoding` is the source of my problem but without having to scan my words and replace the Umlauts by the matching two letters (`Ä` -> `AE`), how can I proceed to calculate precisely the length of my strings ?

Edit : I consider the correct length is `10`.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: save the source file as UTF-8 already tried that?

Comment: What would you consider to be the correct string length here - 9 or 10 ?

Comment: Sounds like a weird bug in N++, if you ask me. Then again, I thought it was Unicode aware.

Comment: @AndyM Your edit doesn’t make sense. The correct length is 9 – why should it be 10?

Comment: @AndyM Why is the correct length 10? otherwise convert it to ASCII so get the bytes from UTF-8 and decode it with ASCII

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually, I'm generating a file for another software and this software needs the length to be 10 (in my example).

Comment: `Ä` is one char, so why do you want to count it as two?

Comment: StringInfo.LengthInTextElements could help you out

Comment: Just use `UTF8.GetBytes(string).Length` if you want the 'file' length.

Comment: @Winbo : Nope, tried, it doesn't work for me !

Comment: @AndyM: You want the byte count in some given encoding. Although your need may be legitimate, this is a metrics of one of the many ways to store the string in computer memory. It is not the same as the string length, which has nothing to do with computers whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(l_stest)` looks like it'll get the length you want.

Comment: +1: Even better! Did not know about the `GetByteCount` method.

Comment: @Rawling: Oh, I think you're my saver! I'm giving it a go, will accept in a few minutes...