# asp.net 4.5 TextBox HTML Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx that cotains this code:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server"
                  ID="VeranstaltungDetailForm"
                  ItemType="Budgetverwaltung.Models.Veranstaltung"
                  DataKeyNames="VeranstaltungsId"
                  SelectMethod="GetItem"
                  InsertMethod="InsertItem"
                  UpdateMethod="UpdateItem"
                  OnDataBinding="VeranstaltungDetailForm_DataBinding"
                  OnDataBound="VeranstaltungDetailForm_DataBound"
                  OnItemCommand="VeranstaltungDetailForm_ItemCommand">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><%#: Item.Bezeichnung %> (<%#: Item.Veranstaltungsnummer %>)</legend>
                <table class="content-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Beschreibung:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><%#: Item.Beschreibung %></td>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Ort:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><%# Item.Ort %></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Neue Veranstaltung anlegen</legend>
                  <table class="content-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Beschreibung:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="insert_beschreibung" Text="<%#: BindItem.Beschreibung %>"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Ort:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="insert_ort" Text="<%#: BindItem.Ort %>"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </InsertItemTemplate>

        <EditItemTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Veranstaltung bearbeiten "<%#: Item.Bezeichnung %>"</legend>
                <dl>
                  <table class="content-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Beschreibung:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="edit_beschreibung"  Text="<%# BindItem.Beschreibung %>"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td class="dark-table"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Ort:</span></td>
                        <td class="light-table"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="edit_ort" Text="<%#: BindItem.Ort %>"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

The data is managed by Entity Framework. In most cases, everything is working fine. But if I enter Umlaute (ÄÖÜ äöü) I run into problems.
When I enter them and save, everything is fine. The Data appears correctly in the database.
When I view the data, e.g. , everything is fine. But when I try to edit the data in  the data gets html-encoded as ÄÖÜ and I can't save it again. I'm no expert at asp.net so I'm at a loss right now. Where is my mistake?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you mean by "gets html-encoded as ÄÖÜ"?

Comment: In the ItemTemplate it is displayed as "ÄÖÜ", in the EditItemTemplate it is displayed as &#196;&#214;&#220;
I can't save it in that state or I will get a HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005).

Answer (score 0):

try to look here :  [String encoding - German umlaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641627/string-encoding-german-umlaut)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the string encoding is the culprit in this case. It must have something to do with the html-encoding or decoding of the data that is taking place automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your configuration I would assume that your content, when *loaded* from the server, is probably character set `UTF-8`, which causes non-UTF-8 characters like 'Ü' to be HTML-encoded. Thus your textbox is displaying the HTML-encoded characters instead of the original `UTF-16` characters - but when rendered in your normal ItemTemplate the browser respects the encoding and this appears perfectly fine.

You could try to force UTF-16 encoding on all responses using [this approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx) in your web.config which should ensure that your umlaut characters never get encoded in a response:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-16" responseEncoding="utf-16" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

YMMV.